# Redirect to a different domain using nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am attempting to redirect to a different url using the following server config.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 301 http://anotherdomain.com;
 }
```

When you type in www.domain.com it is successfully redirected to `http://anotherdomain.com`, but when you type in domain.com it seems like what happens is it gets redirected to `http://http//anotherdomain.com`

I tried looking at the nginx docs and also tried:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    rewrite ^ http://anotherdomain.com permanent;
 }
```

I ended up with the same results.
I'm sure I am missing something obvious but can someone point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot the trailing slash. Beyond that, look at your application.

Comment: Does both domains resolve to the same address?

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it.

Did you try switching server_name values around?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
    rewrite ^ http://anotherdomain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

You could also try this variant

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://anotherdomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.anotherdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Let me know how it goes